# How can I use setText instead of using append in android studio?

Tags: android, api, append, retrofit, settext

I'm trying to use RETROFIT to get an inform about COVID-19 data. And I want to show the latest data, so I tried

```
content1 = covid_post_data.getPositive() + "\n";
content2 = covid_post_data.getDeath() + "\n";
content3 = " (+" + covid_post_data.getPositiveIncrease() + ")\n";
content4 = " (+" + covid_post_data.getDeathIncrease() + ")\n";
content5 = " Updated : " + covid_post_data.getDate() + "\n";

textViewResult.setText(content1);
textViewResult2.setText(content2);
textViewResult3.setText(content3);
textViewResult4.setText(content4);
textViewResult5.setText(content5);
```

But it is not working.it didn't show any data. how can i show the latest data in JSON file with using retrofit? below is my whole code of main activity

1.MainActivity

```
  public class COVIDActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private TextView textViewResult;
  private TextView textViewResult2;
  private TextView textViewResult3;
  private TextView textViewResult4;
  private TextView textViewResult5;

  private static final String TAG = "COVIDActivity";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.covid_menu);
//How go_back_button works
ImageButton bo_back_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.covid_to_main);
bo_back_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent move_main_covid = new Intent(COVIDActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(move_main_covid);
}
});

textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result_positive);
textViewResult2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result_death);
textViewResult3 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result_positive_increase);
textViewResult4 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result_death_increase);
textViewResult5 = findViewById(R.id.today_date);
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();

JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

Call<List<COVID_Post_Data>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.get_covid_post();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<COVID_Post_Data>>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<COVID_Post_Data>> call, Response<List<COVID_Post_Data>> response) {

if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
textViewResult.setText(("Code: " + response.code()));
return;

}
List<COVID_Post_Data> posts = response.body();

//Give message if fail, TAG is COVIDActivity so that it will show log in this activity
if(posts == null) {
Log.w(TAG,"Did not receive any valid response body");
return;
}

for (COVID_Post_Data covid_post_data : posts) {
String content1,content2,content3,content4,content5 = "";

content1 = covid_post_data.getPositive() + "\n";
content2 = covid_post_data.getDeath() + "\n";
content3 = " (+" + covid_post_data.getPositiveIncrease() + ")\n";
content4 = " (+" + covid_post_data.getDeathIncrease() + ")\n";
content5 = " Updated : " + covid_post_data.getDate() + "\n";
textViewResult.append(content1);
textViewResult2.append(content2);
textViewResult3.append(content3);
textViewResult4.append(content4);
textViewResult5.append(content5);
}
}
```

2.get JSON file

```
    public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    //get data from json about US infection
    @GET("us/daily.json")
    Call<List<COVID_Post_Data>> get_covid_post();

    //get data from json about states infection
   @GET("states/daily.json")
    Call<List<COVID_Post_Data>> get_covid_post_state();
}
```

3.getter function

```
    public class COVID_Post_Data {

    private String dataChecked;
    private int positiveIncrease;
    private int negativeIncrease;
    private int deathIncrease;
    private String state;
    private int positive;
    private int death;
    private int date;

    //if the variable is matched with name in json file no need to put @SerializedName here

    public String getDataChecked() {
return dataChecked;
    }

    public int getPositiveIncrease() {
return positiveIncrease;
    }

    public int getNegativeIncrease() {
return negativeIncrease;
    }

    public int getDeathIncrease() {
return deathIncrease;
    }

    public String getState() {
return state;
    }

    public int getPositive() {
return positive;
    }

    public int getDeath() { return death; }

    public int getDate() {
return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: try: setText(String.valueOf(content1), when values are int

Comment: make a service which will fetch the data from server using retrofit after any interval of time

Comment: it works with setText(String.valueOf(content1), but how can i get the latest version of the data?@armen